# Задача на проверку корней кубического уравнения, Java

Tags: java

Решаю задачки на сайте Hyperskill. В процессе решения [одной](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2190) возникла проблема в "чистоте кода".

Я создал метод на проверку `x` в качестве корня кубического уравнения:

```
static boolean checkRoot(int a, int b, int c, int d, int x) {
    if (a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

В процессе решения метод нормально используется, но мне выдаётся замечание:

> Avoid unnecessary if..then..else statements when returning booleans

Как только начинаю убирать кажущуюся ненужным часть с else - сразу вылезает ошибка:

> Compilation error Main.java:52: error: missing return statement
>       }
>       ^ 1 error

Не пойму - это баг системы и надо писать им в саппорт, или действительно, метод

```
static boolean checkRoot(int a, int b, int c, int d, int x) {
    if (a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d == 0) {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

задан неверно?

Comment: где второй return?

Comment: a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d - поместите это в новую переменную, а потом сравнивайте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static boolean checkRoot(int a, int b, int c, int d, int x) {
    return a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d == 0;
}
```

Ваш условный оператор сам по себе возвращает boolean, поэтому вам достаточно вернуть то значение, которое находится в скобках условного оператора.
Ваш последний вариант не компилируется потому, что вы возвращаете true только при выполнении указанного условия, при этом утрачена инструкция возврата в том случае, когда это условие не выполняется, следовательно, ошибка компиляции. все просто)

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо!